# Regression Interpretation

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

i have a regression where dependent variable is a share variable that ranges between 0 and 100%.

And independent variables are % variables, like let's say % of people in a specific age group. Suppose, the regression equation is like Y=0.5X1,+0.3X2+intercept...

I want to know how to interpret. Can i say, for a 1% change in X1 (which is a percentage variable), the Y goes up by 0.3%? (keeping all other variables constant).Likewise, can we say, if i change X2 by 1%, Y goes up by 0.2%? (keeping X1 constant)

Also, how to quantify this part - keep all other variables constant. Should i keep the others at average?.Basically, i want to know mathematically, what number should i report for a 1% increase in X1 and 1% increase in X2?

Please let me know, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Ok for simplicity, let's ignore the fact that your independent and dependent variable are percentages

$$y= intercept+ 0.5 x_1 + 0.3 x_2$$

Typically the interpretation is,

- for every 1 unit increase in $x_1$, $y$ increases by 0.5
- for every 1 unit increase in $x_2$, $y$ increases by 0.3

Now, let's add make all your variables percentages. The problem with this is that your model can predict outside of the range of what is possible. For example, if $intercept=0.7$ and $x_1=0.5$ and $x_2=0.5$ then $y=0.7+0.25+0.15=1.1>1$.

In effect, the percentage data is not a problem for independent(since these are already given to you) variables but it is a problem for dependent variables. Therefore, you need a mapping from $(0,1)$ to the ${\rm I\!R}$. The log transformation is a typical one (also known as logistic regression).

$$log(\frac{y}{1-y})= intercept+ \alpha x_1 + \beta x_2$$

So you should fit your model to estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ this way. The interpretation then becomes

- for every $0.1$ increase in $x_1$, the log odds of $y$ increases by $0.1 \alpha$
- for every $0.1$ increase in $x_2$, the log odds of $y$ increases by $0.1 \beta$